# cassandra on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: cassandra

The package seems to be unavailable for this version.

Comment: @ Ashraful : I have already tried all these commands but it doesn't work as if the system is flanged so that it does not work on armhr architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is two years old, I just wanted to add an answer here because I was hitting the same problem on Raspbian Stretch.

Yes, the official Cassandra Debian package does not support "armhf" that is used in Raspberry Pi 3. But you can install Cassandra by using its tarball. For example:

1. download the tarball from [here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/cassandra/3.11.4/apache-cassandra-3.11.4-bin.tar.gz) (for VERSION 3.11.4).
2. run `tar zxvf apache-cassandra-$VERSION.tar.gz`
3. run `cd apache-cassandra-$VERSION`
4. bring up locally: `bin/cassandra -f`

As Cassandra is written in Java (1.8), it will just run as long as you have Java 8 and Python 2.7 installed.

Btw, if you hit an "insufficient memory" problem, you can create additional swap file (as in linux) and then re-run.

Comment: It worked for me today using the most current version 3.11.5

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no armhf package provided by officials, the best way is to install Cassandra tar.gz file from scratch.

An alternative is to bring up C* in a docker container in rpi board. I have built a C* docker image for arm based device and is available on docker hub.

Please note that the base image is based on ARM architecture. You may build the image on raspberry pi or simulate an arm based OS in VM

Comment: There is now an official docker image (arm64) for Cassandra: https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra